# Get Value from array and write to html file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I have the following source:

```js
var testext = {
    "key1": "String1/1",
    "key2": "String2/1",
    "key4": "String4/1",
};

for (i = 0; i < testext.length; i++) {
    if (testext["key" + i]) {
        var outouter = "key: " + testext["key" + i];
        document.getElementById("id" + i).innerHTML = outouter;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Testpage with array values</p>

<div id="id1">Nothing set 1</div>
<div id="id2">Nothing set 2</div>
<div id="id3">Nothing set 3</div>
<div id="id4">Nothing set 4</div>
<div id="id5">Nothing set 5</div>
```

The way this is supposed to work is that the loop takes all the keys in the table and checks if there is a value to them and than writes that value to the div the value is there for.

If possible it would be great to have a key div mapping like `key1 -> sorter`, `key2 -> boarder`, `key3 -> cars` and so on, but this is far over my reach so I stick to the counting version.

The output should be:

```
String1/1
String2/1
Nothing set 3
String4/1
Nothing set 5
```

But for some reason this is not working. Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: Javascript object  doesn't have a 'length' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged jQuery, why not use jQuery:

```js
var testext = {
    "key1": "String1/1",
    "key2": "String2/1",
    "key4": "String4/1",
};

$("div").html(function () {
    var key = this.id.replace("id", "key");
    return (key in testext) ? testext[key] : this.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Testpage with array values</p>

<div id="id1">Nothing set 1</div>
<div id="id2">Nothing set 2</div>
<div id="id3">Nothing set 3</div>
<div id="id4">Nothing set 4</div>
<div id="id5">Nothing set 5</div>
```

This makes use of the fact that jQuery methods such as `.html()` run on *all* selected elements, all `div` elements in this case. They are, in fact, loops. Therefore we don't need to write a `for` loop ourselves.

Whatever you return from the function becomes the element's new HTML.

---

Since setting an element's HTML without actually changing it is not very efficient, we can turn it around:

```js
var testext = {
    "key1": "String1/1",
    "key2": "String2/1",
    "key4": "String4/1",
};

$.each(testext, function (key, val) {
    var id = key.replace("key", "id");
    $("#" + id).html(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Testpage with array values</p>

<div id="id1">Nothing set 1</div>
<div id="id2">Nothing set 2</div>
<div id="id3">Nothing set 3</div>
<div id="id4">Nothing set 4</div>
<div id="id5">Nothing set 5</div>
```

This makes use of the fact that jQuery's `$.each()` helper method can loop over objects. In this sample we only change the HTML of elements that have a counterpart in the `testext` object.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. Just if it is possible, is there a way to use 

ids like car, chair, table, masks,  

and keys like key1, key2, key3 

and map them like car->key1, chair->key2, masks -> key3 

with the source above??

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: var testext = {
    "key1": "String1/1",
    "key2": "String2/1",
    "key4": "String4/1",
};

<div id="car">Nothing set 1</div>
    <div id="chair">Nothing set 2</div>
    <div id="table">Nothing set 3</div>
    <div id="masks">Nothing set 4</div>

There is no counter on both sides. I wanted to ask if you can map something like this as well. Like map: key1->chair, key2-> table, key3-> masks

Comment: No, that's not possible because objects are unordered. You should not try to do that. If you want an ordered list of items, use an array. If you want key->value associations, use an object. There is no such thing as the "third thing" in an object.

Answer (score 3):

testtext is an object and not an array, so i just changed the for loop below, and getting number from key done using a regular expression. i checked, its working

```
    <body>
    <p>Testpage with array values</p>

    <div id="id1">Nothing set 1</div>
    <div id="id2">Nothing set 2</div>
    <div id="id3">Nothing set 3</div>
    <div id="id4">Nothing set 4</div>
    <div id="id5">Nothing set 5</div>

    <script>
    var testext = {
      "key1": "String1/1",
      "key2": "String2/1",
      "key4": "String4/1",
    };

    for(key in testext) {
    var outouter = testext[key];
  document.getElementById("id" + key.replace( /^\D+/g, '')).innerHTML = outouter;
}




</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. Just if it is possible, is there a way to use ids like car, chair, table, masks, and keys like key1, key2, key3 and map them like car->key1, chair->key2, masks -> key3 with the source above??

Comment: Warning: `for .. in` (at least without a guarding `.hasOwnProperty`) is not the recommended way of looping over object keys. Using `Object.keys(testext).forEach(...)` is a lot better.